# Submitting form with Html.ActionLink submit inside an Ajax Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have an AJAX.BeginForm() form and I want to submit an Html post as the final post. Here's my form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("createSet", "Workout", 
new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divs", 
HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    <div id="divs">
        @Html.Partial("WorkoutSet", Session["WorkoutSetList"])
    </div>

    @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "SavePlan", "Workout", new { type = "submit" });
    //<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="command" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create Set" name="command" />

}
```

Basically my "create set" button is used a lot for ajax calls which is working fine. I'm able to bind the model rendered from the partial view and update my model to session on every ajax call.

For my final step, I want to submit the whole form to the `SavePlan` Action along with the model values and then redirect to home page after that.

Problems faced:

- First I tried the Ajax `Submit` button(the code commented out), a script redirects it to the `SavePlan` along with the model values rendered from partialview. Only problem is I could not redirect to `HomePage` and I've read that redirection cannot be done on an ajax call.
- Second, I've tried the `@Html.ActionLink` which does goes to the `SavePlan` action and then proceeds to redirect to `HomePage`, BUT the model values were never passed. I've tried `FormCollection` but the values don't get passed either.

Please provide some advise on how to solve this? I've already spent 2 days on it and I'm tearing myself on it.

To recap:

- Trying the Ajax way allows me to pass the model values but does not redirect to home page
- Trying the Html way doesn't allow me to pass the model values but does redirect to home page.

Comment: Why do you want to do ajax post back when you want to perform  redirection?

Comment: What is the difference between your controller methods `createSet` and `SavePlan`? A better approach would be to use a standard `Html.BeginForm` with a submit button for `SavePlan` and then handle the click event of a "Create Set" button that uses ajax to update the DOM.

Comment: @Venkat : Because my model is tied to the ajax form. I wanted to make sure any changes to the form is saved one last time before I perform the redirection

Comment: @StephenMuecke `createSet` adds new set rows. `SavePlan` saves the plan to the database and then redirects.  I do a ajax call passing the model values as well and returning with new rows and updating any changes to the model. using html form, i'm not sure if I can bind the models when i perform the ajax call.

Comment: Yes you can bind to your models using ajax (your are in effect doing just that with `@Html.BeginForm`), although I really don't understand what your trying to achieve. If your wanting to dynamically add rows, you could just do this with jquery (without any ajax call to a controller)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Oh it's not my call. Team wants me to add rows and update the model server side on every new row added. Because the user is most likely to fill up some data before adding a new row, team wanted that data to be captured and stored somewhere. Anyways I got the answer I was looking from Carl, but thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect from an ajax POST - in your controller, you need to return a window.location javascript snippet:

```
return JavaScript(string.format("window.location = '{0}'", Url.Action("Index")));
```

There is an article here: [Breaking out of an AJAX POST](http://www.trycatchexfinally.co.uk/posts/mvc-ajax-full-redirect)

Comment: :This one looks promising. I'm going to try it and let you know.

Comment: Hmm wasn't sure how to edit my previous comment. But your answer worked for me!!. Thanks a lot Carl. Although I had to add a controller to the url and it was `String` syntax. Just for anyone out there who might run into this prob. Thanks again.